# How do I subtract from the same table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table measurements that has data like below.

```
week   hips    wrist    abs    weight
1      26.3    6.3      24.3    100
2      25.2    6.3      23.3    96
```

I am trying to get the result  from week 2 to week one

```
hips    wrist    abs    weight
-1.1    0        -1      -4
```

I tried joining the tables on each other and subtracting but I kept getting duplicates.  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Are there trials from multiple subjects in the table?

Comment: Yea the normal table has a challenge number and contact number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
select mprev.hips - m.hips as hips,
       mprev.wrist - m.wrist  as wrist,
       mprev.abs - m.abs as abs,
       mprev.weight - m.weight as weight
from measurements m join
     measurements mprev
     on me.week = mprev.week + 1;
```

Comment: I used yours.  I had to reverse the m.hips and mprev.hips

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 a.[hips]-b.hips as Hips
, a.wrist - b.wrist as Wrist
, a.abs - b.abs as Abs
, a.weight - b.weight as Weight
FROM
tableName a
LEFT JOIN
tableName b
ON
a.week-1=b.week
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
SELECT VAR(hips) AS hips, VAR(wrist) AS wrist,
       VAR(abs) AS abs, VAR(weight) AS weight
FROM measurements
WHERE week IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason the weeks aren't in order, you can use this as well:

```
;With Data As
(
    Select  hips, wrist, [abs], [weight],
            Row_Number() Over (Order By Week) RN
    From    Measurements
)
Select  Cur.Hips - Prev.Hips            As Hips,
        Cur.Wrist - Prev.Wrist          As Wrist,
        Cur.[Abs] - Prev.[Abs]          As [Abs],
        Cur.[Weight] - Prev.[Weight]    As [Weight]
From    Data Prev
Join    Data Cur On Cur.RN = Prev.RN + 1
```